# Show a moving bus in google maps api v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, overlay, google-maps-android-api-2, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to show the position of a moving bus in google maps api v2 in an android application. I am able to mark the stops and draw routes using the markers and polylines. Now, I am trying to have an image(bus/Marker) that moves along the route that is there in the map. I am using GroundOverlay to achieve this, but I am not able to re draw the moving image/marker using GroundOverlay.

The problem I am facing is that, as I am drawing the map in the OnCreate function, the map, markers, routes and all the positions of the moving marker are displayed only once at the end of the oncreate function. I think I am going in the wrong direction. Is there a way to redraw only the moving marker? Is it possible to have a view on top of a map and draw on the view using projection? (is this possible in V2? If Yes, do we have some demo or sample available online?)

Comment: Looks like Google Maps v2 documentation sucks big time... here is a similar question ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2

Comment: Example screenshots of what you want to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: I found answer to my question here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872803/how-to-animate-marker-in-android-map-api-v2?rq=1
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android