# Animating markers on OpenStreet Maps using osmdroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I'm using the google Maps marker animation logic given [here](https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689).

My marker gets animated,but after each `marker.setPosition(newPosition);`
I need to call `mapView.invalidate();`which refreshes the map resulting in very sluggish animation.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: What kind of animation do you try to apply? Do you want to animate movements of the marker (like a moving car animation) or just apply some animation on static marker (like blinking animation)?

Comment: @Dmitry i have the same question too . how to animate a route between a route instead of drawing line between them ?

Comment: @Reza Do you want to animate marker movement from point A to point B? The simplest solution would be this:
 mapController.animateTo(myLocation.getGeoPoint());
Or you may want to give a try to OSMBonusPack: https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack

Comment: @Dmitry thanks . i want to animate a car moving from departure to destination .  i couldn't find any solution  and osmbounspack does not have such capability.

Comment: @Reza I believe you have to implement this kind of animation by youself.
I can think about couple ways of doing this: (1) update location on your car on the map and use method animateTo(<car_location_geopoint>) to keep you car in the center of the map; (2) create another layout on the top of the map and place your icon of the car in the center of this layout; then use method animateTo(<car_location_geopoint>) to keep the map centered on location of the car.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next solution is working correctly for me:

```
import org.osmdroid.api.IGeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.api.IMapController;
import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.views.Projection;
import org.osmdroid.views.overlay.Marker;

public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final GeoPoint toPosition) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = map.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toPixels(marker.getPosition(), null);
    final IGeoPoint startGeoPoint = proj.fromPixels(startPoint.x, startPoint.y);
    final long duration = 500;
    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.getLongitude() + (1 - t) * startGeoPoint.getLongitude();
            double lat = t * toPosition.getLatitude() + (1 - t) * startGeoPoint.getLatitude();
            marker.setPosition(new GeoPoint(lat, lng));
            if (t < 1.0) {
                handler.postDelayed(this, 15);
            }
            map.postInvalidate();
        }
    });
}
```

It is based on the same implementation done by some people for GoogleMaps v2, but adapted to osmdroid.

The source where I found the implementation for GoogleMaps v2 is here: 
[How to animate marker in android map api V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872803/how-to-animate-marker-in-android-map-api-v2)

I am using:
    osmdroid-android 5.5 and osmbonuspack 6.0

Comment: Works great on _osmdroid-android_ 6.0.1. Also, `Marker` is included in Osmdroid & it does not require _osmbonuspack_