# Animate a ride on a route in a map view in android

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline, simulate

In google map v2 i have done well with drawing a polyline for the route from a position(LatLong) to another.
But what i need is to simulate that a car is driving on this polyline and the car will rotate to stay straight with the route until it reaches the target position.
Please help even if you dont know the code just give me a description of the solution

Comment: These might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872803/how-to-animate-marker-in-android-map-api-v2?rq=1, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android

Comment: thank you @Verma i will check these links

Comment: thank you @Verma i will check these links

Comment: For animating polyline routes github.com/amalChandran/google-maps-route-animation