# Change the marker size with a smooth animation

Tags: android, animation, google-maps-api-2, marker

I'm working on a map application that should be like PokemonGO or something like that. I'm using Google Map API V2 and a simple MapActivity.

The marker uses a custom image and is centered over the location.

I need to change the size of the marker with a smooth animation (when clicked), I've tried to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32476346/9290955) code but the marker size grows not centered and looks like this:

[image]

the yellow dot represents the location and as you can see is not centered.

Answer (score 0):

Marker icon has options like:

```
icon.origin
icon.anchor
icon.size
icon.scaledSize
```

You have to change them according to new size.

```
icon = marker.getIcon();
```