# Animate tons of markers with Google Map on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, animation, google-maps-markers

I am trying to fade in the markers on a google maps fragment like this:

```
ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1);
animator.setDuration(1000);
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
        marker.setAlpha((float) animation.getAnimatedValue());
    }
});
animator.start();
```

It works perfectly for a single marker but when I try to do it with 200 markers the performance is terrible and the markers just appear without any animation. I'm going nuts here, any help/idea/suggestion would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check on this [related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13872803/how-to-animate-marker-in-android-map-api-v2). It suggested to use the [`Interpolator` class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Interpolator.html) to apply the animation on the Marker and handle it in the Handler for the animation. Check the sample [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15941069/5832311).

Here are some threads which might help:

- [Move markers in google map v2 android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android)
- [How to animate marker when it is added to map on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8191582/how-to-animate-marker-when-it-is-added-to-map-on-android)
- [Animating markers on Google Maps V2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14864664/animating-markers-on-google-maps-v2)