# How to attach a flexible marker on map something like Uber and Lyft?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, android-maps-v2

How to attach a flexible marker on map something like Uber and Lyft ?
am using Google maps v2.

Basically, i want to display a marker on map while the position of the marker is changed upon moving the map.

edited:

Ok i solved my problem.

first : add an imageview to the same layout and position equal to center.
second: to get the coordinate of the center of the map use the following approach

**1- get viewgroup ( FrameLayout ) in my case where the map fragment is located.**

```
FrameLayout myContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
int mapHeight = myContainer.getHeight();
int mapWidth = myContainer.getWidth();
```

**2- use setOnCameraChangeListener and on camera change get the coordinates:**

```
LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

Answer (score 7):

**edited:**

Ok i solved my problem.

first : add an imageview to the same layout and position equal to center. second: to get the coordinate of the center of the map use the following approach

**1- get viewgroup ( FrameLayout ) in my case where the map fragment is located.**

```
FrameLayout myContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
int mapHeight = myContainer.getHeight();
int mapWidth = myContainer.getWidth();
```

**2- use setOnCameraChangeListener and on camera change get the coordinates:**

```
LatLng center = mMap.getCameraPosition().target;
```

Comment: and then? i got center now? zooming in/out moves from the center of the screen