# Android Map v2 static pin

Tags: android, google-maps

I've created an activity which shows a map v2. I would like to create a fixed pin at the center of the map. If panning around the screen the pin stays fixed at the view's center.

I've only found a tutorial showing how to create markers, but they keep they keep scrolling with the map when panning around. As an example, the UBER app uses this kind of fixed pin:
[image]

As you might see, the pin is in the middle of the screen and stays there also when panning around.

Any suggestions how to achieve that?

Comment: you dont put it on the map, what you do is overlay it ontop of the map by putting an imageview in the center of the screen

Comment: Alright, I just thought there is a way how to customize those markers to achieve this ... Thanks for the reply

Comment: Check this.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504606/how-to-implement-draggable-map-like-uber-android

Comment: Or check this for another option: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763093/how-to-get-the-location-of-centered-place-pin-on-map-like-uber-android-app/40986622#40986622