# How to listen to custom marker location change in Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I have a Geocoder IntentService that converts latitude and longitude to address. I also have a custom marker image in the exact middle of the screen. I would like to let the user select any location they want by simply dragging the map and place it right under my custom marker. As soon as they do that I would like to get the latitude and longitude of the center of the screen and pass these arguments to the Geocoder class. I tried the following but I only get the current location. And the marker is stuck in the middle, meaning if I drag the map it bounces back to my current location. I am using Google maps api V2.

```
protected void startGeocoderService(final Location lo) {
        map.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
        try {
            LatLng lalng = new LatLng(lo.getLatitude(), lo.getLongitude());
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(lalng, 15));
            LatLng newloatlng = map.getCameraPosition().target;
            lo.setLatitude(newloatlng.latitude);
            lo.setLongitude(newloatlng.longitude);

                Intent myintent = new Intent(MapActivity.this, FetchAddressIntentService.class);
                myintent.putExtra(Constants.RECEIVER, mAddressResultReceiver);
                myintent.putExtra(Constants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, lo);
                startService(myintent);

            }catch (NullPointerException nullexception){
                nullexception.printStackTrace();
            }

            }
        });
    }
```

How can I accomplish that? Thank you in advance everyone for your help

Comment: I think you can use `FrameLayout` to have the `overlap effect` for your map and markers and then call the `onCameraChange` as well as `Geocoder` function. For more details, please refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504606/how-to-implement-draggable-map-like-uber-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `FrameLayout` to have the `overlap effect` for your map and markers and then call the `onCameraChange` as well as `Geocoder` function.

Sample code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:minWidth="180dp"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text=" Set your Location "
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/add_marker" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Selected Location"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#28b54c" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/adressText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="Getting location"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

For more details, please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504606/how-to-implement-draggable-map-like-uber-android).