# Creating draggable map like uber application

Tags: java, android, location, android-mapview, marker

I have followed one link which has the code to make map which we can drag and get the current location. Here is the link. 
[How to Implement draggable map like uber android, Update with change location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504606/how-to-implement-draggable-map-like-uber-android/27504607#27504607)

I have followed all the code still I am unable to get the result. The map we can drag but not showing the location on text view.

ChooseFromMapLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.go_jek.ChooseFromMapActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".ChooseFromMapActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_above="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutUseLoc">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/UseThisLoc"
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_36dp"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textShowAddress"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.83" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView22"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_search_black_48dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

ChooseFromMapActivity

```
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.R;
import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.GData;
import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.GPSTracker;
import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.AppLocationService;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener;

public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    public static String ShopLat;
    public static String ShopPlaceId;
    public static String ShopLong;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
    private TextView markerText;
    private LatLng center;
    private LinearLayout markerLayout;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private TextView Address;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private LatLng curentpoint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
        Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
        markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);
        markerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { 
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
          mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

  mUpdatesRequested = false;

            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    private void stupMap() {
        try {

            mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,
                            new LocationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                    markerText.setText("Location received: "
                                            + location.toString());

                                }
                            });

            Log.e("Reached", "here");

            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {

                    if (status.isSuccess()) {

                        Log.e("Result", "success");

                    } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,
                                    100);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            gps = new GPSTracker(this);

            gps.canGetLocation();

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            mGoogleMap.clear();

            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {

                    center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                    markerText.setText(" Set your Location ");
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {
                        new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });

            markerLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {

                        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(center.latitude,
                                center.longitude);

                        Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng1)
                                .title(" Set your Location ")
                                .snippet("")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_actionloc)));
                        m.setDraggable(true);

                        markerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        stupMap();

    }

    private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        double x, y;
        StringBuilder str;

        public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Address.setText(" Getting location ");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(localityString + "");
                    str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                    str.append(zipcode + "");

                } else {
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

GPSTracker

```
  public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

        private final FragmentActivity mActivity;
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
        boolean canGetLocation = false;
        Location location;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;

        private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10
        private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute
        protected LocationManager locationManager;

        public GPSTracker(FragmentActivity activity) {
            this.mActivity = activity;
            getLocation();
        }

        public Location getLocation() {
            try {
                locationManager = (LocationManager) mActivity
                        .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                        .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                } else {
                    this.canGetLocation = true;

                    if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }
                    if (isGPSEnabled) {
                        if (location == null) {
                            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                    MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                    MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                            if (locationManager != null) {
                                location = locationManager
                                        .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                                updateGPSCoordinates();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error : Location",
                        "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
            }

            return location;
        }

        public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }
        }

        public void stopUsingGPS() {
            if (locationManager != null) {
                locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
                locationManager = null;
            }
        }
        public double getLatitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
            }

            return latitude;
        }
        public double getLongitude() {
            if (location != null) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
            }

            return longitude;
        }
        public boolean canGetLocation() {
            return this.canGetLocation;
        }
        public void showSettingsAlert() {

            if (mActivity == null || mActivity.isFinishing()) {
                return;
            }

            mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            mActivity);
                    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
    alertDialog
                            .setMessage("Your GPS is disabled, Enable GPS in settings or continue with approximate location");
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                                            Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                                    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog,
                                                    int which) {
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.create().show();
                }
            });

        }
        public List<Address> getGeocoderAddress(Context context) {
            if (location != null) {
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.ENGLISH);
                try {
                    List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
                            longitude, 1);
                    return addresses;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // e.printStackTrace();
                    Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder",
                            e);
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

                return addressLine;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public String getLocality(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String locality = address.getLocality();

                return locality;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

                return postalCode;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
 }
        public String getCountryName(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String countryName = address.getCountryName();

                return countryName;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            showSettingsAlert();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            return null;
        }
    }

This below code and functions are showing in gray, not getting used.

    import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.R;
    import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.GData;
    import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.GPSTracker;

      public static String ShopLat;
        public static String ShopPlaceId;
        public static String ShopLong;


     public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

                return addressLine;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }


     public String getLocality(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String locality = address.getLocality();

                return locality;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }


      public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

                return postalCode;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }

      public String getCountryName(Context context) {
            List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                String countryName = address.getCountryName();

                return countryName;
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Whenever you will drag your map `mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener` will be called, you need to check there for latlong and have to use geocoder to get address, Please check at that point if it is being called or not, right now.

Comment: In your code new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();
this is called on mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener.. Do I need to call geocoder in on  mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener??

Comment: Nothing happens when I drag the map. I tried putting break point on  mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener and  new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();
this. But it dose not get execute only.

Comment: import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.GPSTracker;  import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.R;
import com.example.siddhi.go_jek.GData;   This packages I am importing but its not getting used its showing in grey color