# Unable to get address when the map is dragged

Tags: java, android, dictionary, drag, uber-api

I am trying to make a map like uber in which we can get the location address when we drag the map. I have seen many links for this and followed this link
[How to Implement draggable map like uber android, Update with change location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504606/how-to-implement-draggable-map-like-uber-android/30346234?noredirect=1#comment55747392_30346234)

But I am unable to get the result. Nothing happens when I drag the map. No exception nothing.. Unable to understand the problem.

ChooseFromMapActivity

```
public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    // A request to connect to Location Services
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

    public static String ShopLat;
    public static String ShopPlaceId;
    public static String ShopLong;
    // Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
    private TextView markerText;
    private LatLng center;
    private LinearLayout markerLayout;
    private Geocoder geocoder;
    private List<Address> addresses;
    private TextView Address;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private GPSTracker gps;
    private LatLng curentpoint;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
        Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
        markerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);


        // Getting Google Play availability status
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { // Google Play Services are
            // not available

            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                    requestCode);
            dialog.show();

        } else { // Google Play Services are available

            // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
            // Create a new global location parameters object
            mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();

            /*
             * Set the update interval
             */
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Use high accuracy
            mLocationRequest
                    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

            // Set the interval ceiling to one minute
            mLocationRequest
                    .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

            // Note that location updates are off until the user turns them on
            mUpdatesRequested = false;

            /*
             * Create a new location client, using the enclosing class to handle
             * callbacks.
             */
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    private void stupMap() {
        try {

            mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                    R.id.map)).getMap();

            // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

            PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                    .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,
                            new LocationListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                    markerText.setText("Location received: "
                                            + location.toString());

                                }
                            });

            Log.e("Reached", "here");

            result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {

                    if (status.isSuccess()) {

                        Log.e("Result", "success");

                    } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                        // Google provides a way to fix the issue
                        try {
                            status.startResolutionForResult(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,
                                    100);
                        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
            gps = new GPSTracker(ChooseFromMapActivity.this);

            gps.canGetLocation();

            latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            longitude = gps.getLongitude();
            curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();


            mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
            // Clears all the existing markers

            mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                    markerText.setText(" Set your Location ");
                    mGoogleMap.clear();
                    markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    try {
                        new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                .execute();

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }
            });

            markerLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    try {

                        LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(center.latitude,
                                center.longitude);

                        Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(latLng1)
                                .title(" Set your Location ")
                                .snippet("")
                                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                        .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_actionloc)));
                        m.setDraggable(true);

                        markerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }

                }
            });

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stupMap();

    }

    private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // boolean duplicateResponse;
        double x, y;
        StringBuilder str;

        public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

            x = latitude;
            y = longitude;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Address.setText(" Getting location ");
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            try {
                geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                str = new StringBuilder();
                if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                    Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);

                    String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                    String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                    String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                    String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                    str.append(localityString + "");
                    str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                    str.append(zipcode + "");

                } else {
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                        + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

GPSTracker

```
    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;

    // flag for GPS Status
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

    // flag for network status
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    // The minimum distance to change updates in metters
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10
    // metters

    // The minimum time beetwen updates in milliseconds
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

    // Declaring a Location Manager
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // getting GPS status
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            // getting network status
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
                // no network provider is enabled
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                // First get location from Network Provider
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
                // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("Error : Location",
                    "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop using GPS listener Calling this function will stop using GPS in your
     * app
     */

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            locationManager = null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Function to get latitude
     */
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }

        return latitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to get longitude
     */
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    /**
     * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
     */
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    /**
     * Function to show settings alert dialog
     */
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }

/**
 * Get list of address by latitude and longitude
 *
 * @return null or List<Address>
 */
public List<Address>getGeocoderAddress(Context context){
        if(location!=null){
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(context,Locale.ENGLISH);
        try{
        List<Address>addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
        longitude,1);
        return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder",
                        e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Try to get AddressLine
     *
     * @return null or addressLine
     */
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Locality
     *
     * @return null or locality
     */
    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get Postal Code
     *
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to get CountryName
     *
     * @return null or postalCode
     */
    public String getCountryName(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        showSettingsAlert();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ChooseFromMapActivity layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.go_jek.ChooseFromMapActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


    <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".ChooseFromMapActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text=" Set your Location "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_above="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutUseLoc">


                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/UseThisLoc"
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_36dp"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textShowAddress"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.83"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView22"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_search_black_36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Do you want to get location of center point of visible map?

Comment: yes. So when the map is dragged it will show the location which is at center o map.

Answer (score 0):

You can get location of center point of visible map using code :

```
VisibleRegion visibleRegion = googleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion();
Point x = googleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(visibleRegion.farRight);           
Point y = googleMap.getProjection().toScreenLocation(visibleRegion.nearLeft);
Point centerPoint = new Point(x.x / 2, y.y / 2);
LatLng centerFromPoint = googleMap.getProjection().fromScreenLocation(centerPoint);
long longitude = centerFromPoint.longitude;
long latitude = centerFromPoint.latitude;
```

For more clearification you can visit my blog:

http://androidpantiii.blogspot.in/2015/12/get-address-of-center-point-of-google.html