# unable to get current location using google map android

Tags: java, android, dictionary, location, drag

I am developing an app in which we can get the current location when the map is loaded and we can get the location when the map is dragged. I have set the marker at center to get the center point of map. It is as same as uber application. I have followed this link for the code
 [How to Implement draggable map like uber android, Update with change location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504606/how-to-implement-draggable-map-like-uber-android/30346234?noredirect=1#comment55747392_30346234)

But I am unable to get the current location. I tried to debug the code by putting break point on  gps.canGetLocation();

```
        latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        longitude = gps.getLongitude();
```

this. But it dose not get called.

What can be the reason??

ChooseFromMapActivity

```
    public class ChooseFromMapActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
            LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
        // A request to connect to Location Services
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        GoogleMap mGoogleMap;

        public static String ShopLat;
        public static String ShopPlaceId;
        public static String ShopLong;
        // Stores the current instantiation of the location client in this object
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        boolean mUpdatesRequested = false;
        private TextView markerText;
        private LatLng center;
        private LinearLayout markerLayout;
        private Geocoder geocoder;
        private List<Address> addresses;
        private TextView Address;
        double latitude;
        double longitude;
        private GPSTracker gps;
        private LatLng curentpoint;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_choose_from_map);
            Address = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textShowAddress);
            markerText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
            markerLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.locationMarker);

            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                    .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

            if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) { 

                int requestCode = 10;
                Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                        requestCode);
                dialog.show();

            } else { 
                mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
                mLocationRequest.setInterval(GData.UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);

                mLocationRequest
                        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
                mLocationRequest
                        .setFastestInterval(GData.FAST_INTERVAL_CEILING_IN_MILLISECONDS);

                mUpdatesRequested = false;
                mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                        .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        }
        private void stupMap() {
            try {

                mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.map)).getMap();
                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);

                PendingResult<Status> result = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                        .requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest,
                                new LocationListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                                        markerText.setText("Location received: "
                                                + location.toString());
                                    }
                                });

                Log.e("Reached", "here");

                result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {

                        if (status.isSuccess()) {

                            Log.e("Result", "success");

                        } else if (status.hasResolution()) {
                            try {
                                status.startResolutionForResult(ChooseFromMapActivity.this,
                                        100);
                            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                gps = new GPSTracker(ChooseFromMapActivity.this);

                gps.canGetLocation();

                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                curentpoint = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(curentpoint).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

                mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                        .newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                mGoogleMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new OnCameraChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition arg0) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        center = mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition().target;

                        markerText.setText(" Set your Location ");
                        mGoogleMap.clear();
                        markerLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        try {
                            new GetLocationAsync(center.latitude, center.longitude)
                                    .execute();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });

                markerLayout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {

                            LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(center.latitude,
                                    center.longitude);

                            Marker m = mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                    .position(latLng1)
                                    .title(" Set your Location ")
                                    .snippet("")
                                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                            .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_actionloc)));
                            m.setDraggable(true);

                            markerLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                        }
                    }
                });   
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) { 
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
            stupMap();
        }
        private class GetLocationAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            double x, y;
            StringBuilder str;

            public GetLocationAsync(double latitude, double longitude) {
                x = latitude;
                y = longitude;
            }
  @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                Address.setText(" Getting location ");
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) { 
                try {
                    geocoder = new Geocoder(ChooseFromMapActivity.this, Locale.ENGLISH);
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(x, y, 1);
                    str = new StringBuilder();
                    if (Geocoder.isPresent()) {
                        Address returnAddress = addresses.get(0);
                        String localityString = returnAddress.getLocality();
                        String city = returnAddress.getCountryName();
                        String region_code = returnAddress.getCountryCode();
                        String zipcode = returnAddress.getPostalCode();

                        str.append(localityString + "");
                        str.append(city + "" + region_code + "");
                        str.append(zipcode + "");
      } else {
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                }
                return null;
         }
           @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                try {
                    Address.setText(addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)
                            + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " ");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        }
    }
```

GPSTracker

```
    public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;
    double latitude=;
    double longitude=;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; 
    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        getLocation();
    }
    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                    .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                    .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;
                if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                        updateGPSCoordinates();
                    }
                }
                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager
                                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            updateGPSCoordinates();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error : Location",
                    "Impossible to connect to LocationManager", e);
        }

        return location;
    }

    public void updateGPSCoordinates() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
    }

    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
            locationManager = null;
        }
    }
    public double getLatitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }
    public double getLongitude() {
        if (location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }
    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }
    public void showSettingsAlert(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");
        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
public List<Address>getGeocoderAddress(Context context){
        if(location!=null){
        Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(context,Locale.ENGLISH);
        try{
        List<Address>addresses=geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude,
        longitude,1);
        return addresses;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("Error : Geocoder", "Impossible to connect to Geocoder",
                        e);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
    public String getAddressLine(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String addressLine = address.getAddressLine(0);

            return addressLine;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String getLocality(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String locality = address.getLocality();

            return locality;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String getPostalCode(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String postalCode = address.getPostalCode();

            return postalCode;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    public String getCountryName(Context context) {
        List<Address> addresses = getGeocoderAddress(context);
        if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            String countryName = address.getCountryName();

            return countryName;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        showSettingsAlert();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

ChooseFromMapActivity Layout

```
    <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.siddhi.go_jek.ChooseFromMapActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <fragment android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/map"
        tools:context=".ChooseFromMapActivity"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:minWidth="180dp"
            android:paddingLeft="2dp"
            android:paddingRight="2dp"
            android:text=" Set your Location "
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_place_black_48dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_above="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:weightSum="1"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutUseLoc">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:text="@string/UseThisLoc"
                    android:id="@+id/textView23"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_chevron_right_black_36dp"
                    android:textColorHighlight="@android:color/white"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="280dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:id="@+id/textShowAddress"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:weightSum="1">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="262dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="05dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.83"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageView22"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_search_black_36dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" /> 
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Manifest file

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.siddhi.go_jek" >   
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.siddhi.mapdmo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.siddhi.mapdmo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDjQ6onUW2O34wjnrYqsWht48FGGOPVZWI" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".GoSend"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.siddhi.go_jek.MainActivity" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".PickLocationActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pick_location"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ChooseFromMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_choose_from_map"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Can anyone help please?? Thank you..

Answer (score 0):

check this ...it can help you in finding the current location

package com.example.splashscreen;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


public class LocationTests extends Activity implements LocationListener {

    double latitude, longitude;
    private GoogleMap map;






    private final LatLng LOCATION_INDORE = new LatLng(22.7253, 75.8655);
    private final LatLng LOCATION_PUNE = new LatLng(18.5203, 73.8567);


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_location_tests);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0, 0,this);
        LocationManager service = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabledGPS  = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        boolean enabledWiFi = service.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if (!enabledGPS) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "GPS signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intentgo = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intentgo);
        }
        else if(!enabledWiFi) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Network signal not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intentgo2 = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intentgo2);
        }
        initializeMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        map.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

        map =((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_INDORE).title("Source"));
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(LOCATION_PUNE).title("Destination"));

        GPSTracker mGPS = new GPSTracker(this);

        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.texts);
        if(mGPS.canGetLocation ){
            mGPS.getLocation();
            //LatLng LOCATION_MYPOSITION = new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(),mGPS.getLongitude());
            text.setText("Lat"+mGPS.getLatitude()+"Lon"+mGPS.getLongitude());
            map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

            CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(), mGPS.getLongitude()), 17);
            map.animateCamera(update);
            map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(mGPS.getLatitude(),mGPS.getLongitude())).title("Your Current Position"));
        }else{
            text.setText("Unabletofind");
            System.out.println("Unable");
        }

    }

    private void initializeMap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(map == null){
            map= ((MapFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

            if (map == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Map could not be creater", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

    }

    public void onClick_indore(View v){
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_INDORE, 16);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }

    public void onClick_pune(View v){
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_PUNE, 12);
        map.animateCamera(update);

    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        initializeMap();
    }
    public void onClick_search(View v){
        GPSTracker mygps = new GPSTracker(this);
        double startlat = mygps.getLatitude();
        double startlon = mygps.getLongitude();
        Intent nav = new Intent(this,Webviewact.class);
        String url="http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="+startlat+","+startlon+"&daddr=18.5203, 73.8567";
        nav.putExtra("url", url);
        //Intent nav= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=START_LON,START_LAT&daddr=END_LON,END_LAT")); 
        startActivity(nav);
        //  map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    //  CameraUpdate update = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(LOCATION_MYPOSITION, 17);
    //map.animateCamera(update);
        }


    private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener(){

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            map.clear();
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude()));
            marker.title("Current Location");
            marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_CYAN));
            map.addMarker(marker);
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude() ),16));


        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    };


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.location_tests, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Comment: can you paste the log what error you are receiving actually

Comment: ..I am not getting any error or exception. I am jut getting map and marker on It but when I move the map nothing happens.