# how to moves map on google map but keep marker as current location in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new in android.I am suffered from last two days.I have researched lot but i didn't get.I implemented different concept in map but map is not moving.It is showing current location and marker is move with map.I want to keep marker as location picker on map.Marker will pick different location according to map moves. Please help i wasted lot of time to do this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately this is neither a tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can help solve [certain problems](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's **your** job to [put some efforts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in the first place, incl. elementary [(re)search](https://google.com/). Majority of newbies' questions are not unique and has already been answered multiple times. Take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to improve your question before it gets downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by different ways. Simplest - add marker image to `ImageView` over map fragment, something like that:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/marker"
    />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40112760/6950238) question.

Comment: Thanks,I added this But there is problem in what concept i can use to move markar on map in java file.I need only concept.