# Indoor map for android with current location marker

Tags: java, android, indoor-positioning-system

I am implementing an indoor positioning system and have reached the stage where I need to mark the location of a user in a building. I have the floor plan of the building but have no idea how to mark the users location on the floor plan or how to move the marker around. The map should stay static while the the marker indicating current position of the user should be able to move around on the map. Any pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Google Indoor Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/) as described in [this](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/2803784?p=gmm_guidelines&visit_id=0-636406537446990124-2773548357&rd=1) tutorial. Or use [custom map tiles](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/tileoverlay) as in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238) example of [Alex Vasilkov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687154/alex-vasilkov).

Comment: I had a look into this and it is the ideal solution however it requires that the specific building already have a floor plan. I submitted my floor plans to google indoor maps but no idea really when it will be accepted, if it will even be accepted. I have been told it can take days, weeks or months depending on my location. I am in Africa so my prospects are probably in the months range.

Comment: @Jewgioh And what about [custom map tiles](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14833256/6950238)?

Comment: Hey thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I have a second question, is there any function in the API that will simply take latitude/longitude and update the location based on the given latitude/longitude? I looked and there is only something that gives it as a starting location, not updating.

Comment: @Jewgioh You can add marker image to `ImageView` over map fragment, and do with it everything what you want. For details see, for example, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45694765/6950238) answer and link within.

Comment: @Jewgioh For making custom tiles you can use applications like [MapTiler](http://help.maptiler.org/betatest/)

Answer (score 0):

if you know the layout of the routers, you can estimate where you are in the building based on signal strength...
or just use google's api([Indoor Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/about/partners/indoormaps/)), which is discussed in: [How to calculate distance from Wifi router using Signal Strength?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength)