# How to ask user to turn on location

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps

How can I prompt the user to turn on the gps in this way in below image. I tried using the alert dialog method but it takes to the settings view I wanted gps to be turned on without moving to settings activity like the most of the apps do..How can I achieve it [image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android: Drag map while keeping marker at the center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40112760/android-drag-map-while-keeping-marker-at-the-center)

Comment: Easiest solution: just put `ImageView` with marker image over your map.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works in java AndroidX 2020 updated:

```
private void enableLoc() {



    LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);


    LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
            .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

    builder.setAlwaysShow(true);

    Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result =
            LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

    result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {


        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task) {
            try {
                LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                // requests here.

            } catch (ApiException exception) {
                switch (exception.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                        // user a dialog.
                        try {
                            // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                            ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                            // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                            // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                            resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                    Maps.this,
                                    LOCATION_SETTINGS_REQUEST);
                        } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                            // Ignore the error.
                        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
                            // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                        }
                        break;
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                        // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                        // settings so we won't show the dialog.
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code to have permission like google map in your app:

```
private fun checkPermissions(): Boolean {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
            ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }

    private fun requestPermissions() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
            this,
            arrayOf(
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ),
            PERMISSION_ID
        )
    }

    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        if (requestCode == PERMISSION_ID) {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                getLastLocation()
            }
        }
    }
```