# android animate marker using many position

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am developping android app using google maps v2, I get positions of car from data base for one day (around 100 position) and I want to animate marker from the first to the last position  like this [example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip.htm)

any help please.

Comment: now I can just move marker between two position using this methode http://stackoverflow.com/a/13912034/2021663 but it is now working when I tried to use many positions

Comment: Here is a small library that you might find useful 
https://github.com/sdoward/Animated-Markers