# FusedLocationProvider API. Transition Between GPS Locations

Tags: android, google-maps, gps, location, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have been working on retrieving GPS locations using Google's FusedLocationProvider API for about a week now. I have successfully gotten close to retrieving accurate gps data.

Currently the marker jumps around the map, instead I want it to smoothly animate like Google Maps, Waze, etc. I have searched the entire internet looking for a solution and have not found anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use animateCamera() method to set focus to new latlng.

```
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
                new LatLng(17.385044, 78.486671)).zoom(12).build();

googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
```

This will result in smooth transition.

PS:Play with the zoom to make it more realistic.

You are looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android)

Comment: Thank you for your response :) and that will add a camera transition, but i need to be able to smoothly animate the marker as well. Any Ideas?