# Moving a marker between Array of LatLng with a specific velocity

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

How to animate Marker between Array with a specific velocity in kmph on Google Map Android.

I tried **animateMarker** method which is widely available in internet. Am able to move through set of LatLng points but not with a specific velocity.

Can someone help me in moving the object with a specific velocity in KMPH

Answer (score 1):

You might have to use `Physics` here. Below is an algorithm-like-detail which may be helpful.

1. Find out the time that should be consumed from first position to the last one. Let's say if the `Velocity` is `17 km/hr`, and the distance between first and last position is `10 km` then time would be `3600 sec` or `3600000 ms`.
2. Now divide the time for each location in your `Array`. Let's say if you have 100 elements in an `Array`, time between each location would be `36 sec` or `36000 ms`
3. Now define a `Handler` with duration set to `36 sec` or `36000 ms` and try to animate marker within this duration. For that you can use another `Handler` or default method provided by he `API`. Recall it the no of times you have elements in your array with next location every time.

**NOTE**

I found an example too. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728041/move-markers-in-google-map-v2-android) for original post.

```
public void animateMarker(final Marker marker, final LatLng toPosition,
        final boolean hideMarker) {
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    Projection proj = mGoogleMapObject.getProjection();
    Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(marker.getPosition());
    final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);
    final long duration = 500;

    final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
            float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed
                    / duration);
            double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.longitude;
            double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                    * startLatLng.latitude;
            marker.setPosition(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            if (t < 1.0) {
                // Post again 16ms later.
                handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
            } else {
                if (hideMarker) {
                    marker.setVisible(false);
                } else {
                    marker.setVisible(true);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Hope anyone of it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I modified the same method to achieve this.

We need to call this method

```
animateMarker(googleMap, driver, arrayPoints, distance(arrayPoints.get(0), arrayPoints.get(1)) * msForKMTravel, 0);
```

arrayPoints is the LatLng array. msForKMTravel is the microSec for travlling a KM.

Method :::

```
public void animateMarker(final GoogleMap mMap, final Marker marker, final List<LatLng> arrayLications, final double duration, final int step) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Moving from:" + step + "To:" + (step + 1) + "duration" + duration);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        LatLng startPosition = arrayLications.get(step);
        final LatLng toPosition = arrayLications.get(step + 1);
        Projection proj = mMap.getProjection();
        Point startPoint = proj.toScreenLocation(startPosition);
        final LatLng startLatLng = proj.fromScreenLocation(startPoint);

        final Interpolator interpolator = new LinearInterpolator();

        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
                float t = interpolator.getInterpolation((float) (elapsed
                        / duration));
                Log.d(TAG, "interpolator t:" + t + "start :" + start + " elapsed :" + elapsed);
                double lng = t * toPosition.longitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.longitude;
                double lat = t * toPosition.latitude + (1 - t)
                        * startLatLng.latitude;
                LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                Log.d(TAG, "Moving to" + newLatLng);
                marker.setPosition(newLatLng);

                if (t < 1.0) {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
                } else {
                    if (arrayLications.size() > step + 2 && isVisible()) {
                        double distance = distance(arrayLications.get(step + 1), arrayLications.get(step + 2));
                        double time = distance * msForKMTravel;
                        Log.d(TAG, "Go for distance" + distance + " in time " + time);
                        animateMarker(mMap, marker, arrayLications, time, step + 1);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I can not mark this as an answer as am not sure if there is a better solution available for this question.