# How to clear location marker in Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am creating a map application using `GoogleMap`. I have a problem while moving a `CustomMarker` from first to second location with help of location change listener. `CustomMarker` gets duplicated because its maintaining the older position as well while updating to new location. Please refer the below image.

[Duplication of single custom marker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maxhe.jpg)

Comment: Are you using some kind of custom drawable and cloning it? If yes, then don't use clone.

Comment: You can try [this nice code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13912034/1507512) to move the marker without removing it

Answer (score -1):

Why won't you just `clear()` `GoogleMap` in order to remove old marker?

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#clear()